# Can't locate App Store in iTunes for macOS

Tags: itunes, mac, ios-appstore

Every time I launch iTunes on my Mac, there is no App Store item in it and I can't access the apps that I have launched on the App Store. .[image: Screen shot of iTunes]

Comment: There is no App Store in iTunes since v12.7 - Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332487/install-app-on-ios-without-using-itunes , https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316896/how-do-i-view-the-ios-app-store-on-a-mac-os-x-10-11-6 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298391/how-do-i-download-an-ios-app-ipa-file-to-my-mac-after-itunes-12-7-update/307430#307430

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check that the iTunes Store is not disabled in the *Restrictions* pane in iTunes preferences (see screenshot below).

[image: iTunes Restrictions preferences]

App Store functionality has been removed in iTunes 12.7 and later.

Apple provides a version of iTunes which still contains the App section and App Store.
Please see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208079 for more info and download link.

This version (12.6.5) can be installed even if a newer version of iTunes exists on your machine (it replaces the newer version). It also stops iTunes from updating (e.g. after installing, iTunes stays at v12.6.5).
It does not work in macOS 10.14 Mojave, though.

Comment: It appears that OP is looking to access the (iOS) App Store and not the iTunes Store. App Store is not available in the recent versions of iTunes.

Comment: @NimeshNeema - agreed; however that setting does remove all except the Library menu item, which I hadn't noticed before. Of course, it won't bring back the App Store itself, only the music store, but it does bring back the menus.

Comment: @Gummibando Please edit the answer to mention it explicitly.

Comment: how may i install the iTunes 12.6.5 my current itunes is 12.8.0.